# Boost how to create a map for types selection?

Tags: c++, boost, types, dictionary, boost-extension

so i [use BOOST.EXTENTION](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html) to load modules. I have a special file that describes each module. I read variables from that file.

so [such example:](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/boost_extension/shared_libraries/shared_library_class.html)

```
shared_library m("my_module_name");
// Call a function that returns an int and takes a float parameter.
int result = m.get<int, float>("function_name")(5.0f);
m.close();
```

for me would turn into:

```
shared_library m("my_module_name");
// Call a function that returns an int and takes a float parameter.
int result = m.get<myMap["TYPE_1_IN_STRING_FORM"], myMap["TYPE_2_IN_STRING_FORM"]>("function_name")(5.0f);
m.close();
```

How to create such map that would map standard and costume types?

**Update:**

may be with [variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html):

```
  shared_library m("my_module_name");
  int result = m.get<boost::variant< int, float, ... other types we want to support >, boost::variant< int, float, ... other types we want to support > >("function_name")(5.0f);
    m.close();
```

can halp? so we would not care as long as all types we want are declared in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you would need a heterogeneous map - that is, its elements can be of different types. Furthermore you would need the ability to return **types** from functions, not just variables.

---

Now, a heterogeneous map would be possible with [`Boost.Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html) or a simple `union`, but that binds it to compile time: we need to know every type that is possible to create that variant/union.
Of course a [`Boost.Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any.html) would be possible to store everything and its dog, but the problem strikes again: you need to extract the *real* type out of that `Boost.Any` again. The problem repeats itself. And if you know the real type, you can aswell just make a variant/union and save yourself the `any_cast` trouble.

---

Now, for another troublesome thing:

```
m.get<myMap["TYPE_1_IN_STRING_FORM"], myMap["TYPE_2_IN_STRING_FORM"]>
```

To make the above line work, you'd need two features that C++ doesn't have: the ability to **return types** and **runtime templates**. Lets ignore the first point for a moment.
Templates are **compile-time**, and the `get` function is such a template. Now, to use that template, your `myMap` would need to be able to return types at **compile-time**, while getting populated at **runtime**. See the contradiction? That's why runtime templates would be needed.

---

Sadly, exactly those three things are not possible (or extremely hard and very very limited) in C++ at runtime: **heterogeneous** data types (without constant size), returning **types** and **templates**.
Everything that involves types needs to be done at **compile-time**. [This blogpost](http://www.gmannickg.com/?p=47) by @Gman somewhat correlates with that problem. It's definitly worth a read if you want to know what C++ just *can't* do.

---

So, to conclude: You'll need to rethink and refactor your problem and solution. :|

Comment: So.. If I want to have a limited types support can boos::variant solve problem? (see post update)

Comment: @Blender : [boost.fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/index.html) contains heterogeneous maps, but they map from heterogeneous types to values, not from homogeneous values to heterogeneous types as is needed here.