# C++ Mapping Types/Functionality between enums(BETTER_ENUMS) and types

Tags: c++, templates, types, enums

I'm using [better enums package](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums)
Having 1:1 mapping between better enum  values and better enum types/functionality
For example

- better enum A[a1, a2]
- better enum B1
- better enum B2

So the logical mapping is:

- A::a1  mapped to  B1 type
- A:a2  mapped to B2 type

```
   BETTER_ENUM(A, int, a1, a2)
   BETTER_ENUM(B1, int, b11, b12, b13)
   BETTER_ENUM(B2, int, b21, b22, b23, b24)
```

Obviously the above example is of size two, but real code would have to support its growth
So basically in order to support this mapping used switch case as below, but this code is hard to maintain and extend:

```
bool Execute1(A a_val)
{
    switch (a_val)
    {
    case A::a1:
        return execute1<B1>();
    case A::a2:
        return execute1<B2>();
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}

int Execute2(A a_val)
{
    switch (a_val)
    {
    case A::a1:
        return execute2<B1>();
    case A::a2:
        return execute2<B2>();
    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to generalize this mapping , and use some design pattern that doesn't require as above switch/case?

Comment: How do you use `a1` or `a2`? Runtime variable or constexpr variable?

Comment: given by user, it's not constexpr, "Execute" methods get arbitrary values when called

Comment: seems there is already similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694255/boost-how-to-create-a-map-for-types-selection)